# Install Qt library(qwt-6.0.1) in windows 7

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I downloaded “Qt 5.0.0 Beta 2” and I downloaded MinGw with gcc version 4.6.2. I extracted the latest “qwt-6.0.1” to the Qt installed folder. All the paths are set.
Now I opened "Qt 5.0.0 for Desktop(MSVC 2010)" command prompt. After changing the directory to qwt-6.0.1 steps i follwed=>

1) qmake qwt.pro => with this makefile is created
2)make => giving the error... also instead of this step i tried "mingw32-make" command in the same prompt.. both are giving the same error following error :

Error : "cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\QtSDK\5.0.0-beta2\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe C
:\QtSDK\qwt-6.0.0-rc5\src\src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/QtSDK/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/src'
make -f Makefile.Release all
make[2]: Entering directory`C:/QtSDK/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/src'
Makefile.Release:255: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/QtSDK/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/src'
make[1]: *** [release-all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`C:/QtSDK/qwt-6.0.0-rc5/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2"

Comment: you can't have directory with hypen in windows, qwt-6.0.0-rc5 is invalid for building purposes.  Make directory non hypenated, run qmake qwt.pro, nmake, nmake install.

Answer (score 1):

Qwt from SVN trunk ( aka 6.1 ) works with Qt 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use qwt, an independent library, with Qt 5. Well Qt 5 is recent and not widespread yet, so don't expect much.

It seems that the latest version of qwt on the repository use Qt 4.8 ([see install in svn repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/qwt/code/1552/tree/trunk/qwt/INSTALL)).
It will not work with Qt 5.